# How to include JS/CSS files from subfolders

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kooboo

How do I make sure JavaScript and CSS files in subfolders are included / excluded from being rendered by the `RegisterScripts()` method?

Is it possible to use `WebResource.config` for site themes?

Comment: Its not supported yet. According to Kooboo developers it is planned.

Comment: I added a Git Hub issue to officially request new functionality that should cover the requirements in this question.  If it helps, track the issue here: https://github.com/Kooboo/CMS/issues/302

Comment: If you are using Kooboo, can you add your support please to the Area 51 proposal for a dedicated Kooboo Stack Exchange sub site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79383/kooboo